# Does ctrl+shift+F work in LPCxpresso?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on LPCxpresso. I wanted to find the function in the project but i am able to find it only in single file. I want to find that function in all the files present in the project. I have tried ctrl+shift+F but it didn't work.  And when I try ctrl+F (i.e. Find/Replace) then i get :
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyEQM.png)

In above screen shot if I click "Find". It shows the function used only in the opened file and not in the other files present in the project.

Is there another shortcut for searching something throughout the project?

Please Help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in Window->Preferences->General->Keys

Comment: Thank you sir! I got the answer of my question few days back. we need to use Ctrl+H.